# AttributeError: Cannot access callable attribute 'nlargest' of 'DataFrameGroupBy' objects

Tags: python, pandas-groupby

[Data Overview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HIkVx.png)

Hello everyone
I need to get the two platforms with the most visits per day for one year in total. So:

1. Group the data by day
2. Extract the two platforms with most visits for each day

I tried this code:

```
df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key="Datum", freq="1D")).nlargest(2, 'Visits')
```

and got that error:

```
AttributeError: Cannot access callable attribute 'nlargest' of 'DataFrameGroupBy' objects, try using the 'apply' method
```

Thanks a lot for your help! :)

Comment: Please read [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) and [edit] your question accordingly.

Comment: The point wasn't to remove your error. We want the code and error but put them in the question as code blocks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just use `apply`, as the error message states:

```
import pandas as pd

# dataframe example
d = {'Platform': ['location', 'office', 'station'], 'Date': ['01.08.2019', '01.08.2019', '01.08.2019'], 'Visits': [4372, 48176, 2012]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)


df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key="Date")).apply(lambda grp: grp.nlargest(2, 'Visits'))
```

Comment: Great, this works. Thanks a lot! Very appreciated! :)

Comment: Also, the Grouper is not needed for the nlargest to work with the groupby, for more general data than dates.